# I have built a regex but there is an issue

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have this regex as follows

```
/^\S(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])\S
```

it does most of what's its suppose to do such as must be eight characters long have at least one uppercase character one lowercase and one number however the problem is that it accepts any special characters at the end of the string even it passes the other validation i can't have this can someone modify this regex that it keeps the same functionality mentioned before but does not accept any special characters at all. Oh this is for php and javascript i use this both for client side and server side validation of a password any clues as to where the regex fails is greatly appreciated.

Comment: well you do not specify the end of line.

Comment: why is this tagged as javascript *and* php?

Comment: Please search this site for *regex password validation*. I'm absolutely certain that you'll find one of those 900+ results that has the same requirements as you that has been answered here before.

Comment: You may benefit from [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})$/`](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%28%3F%3D.*%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5BA-Z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5B0-9%5D%29%28%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%7B8%2C%7D%29%24%2F) (click for diagram)

I assumed you meant *at least* 8 characters.  If not, then you need `{8}` (exactly 8) instead of `{8,}` (at least 8)

I assumed "no special characters" means only alphabetic and numeric characters, `[a-zA-Z0-9]` if any other characters are to be allowed, then you can add them here.

Tests here: https://regex101.com/r/QW2qbo/1/

Comment: Thank you your modification did the trick I am grateful

Comment: `{8}` should be adequate to specify 'exactly 8'.

Comment: Yes of course @PJSCopeland

Answer (score 0):

You should use a bunch of `RegExp`s for that:

```
/* javascript */
if(yourString.length > 7 && /[A-Z]/.test(yourString) && /[a-z]/.test(yourString) && /\d/.test(yourString)){
  // pass - ajax to test on server if done with submission
else{
  //fail
}
```

PHP validation, assuming you have passed the correct post values to the Server via AJAX, could look like:

```
<?php
$response = array('good' => false);
if(isset($_POST['eight_or_more']){ // you can ajax string as any valid prop name
  $eom = $_POST['eight_or_more'];
  if(count($eom) > 7 && preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $eom) && preg_match('/[a-z]/', $eom) && preg_match('/\d/', $eom)){
  $response['good'] = true;
}
echo json_encode(response); // now JavaScript should look for resp ajax data argument - if(data.good){ }
?>
```